# Split string in AWK using multi-character delimiter

Tags: bash, awk, split

I have the following delimiter and string:

```
DEL=":::"
STR="info1"$DEL"info2"$DEL"info3"
```

I want to extract info1-2-3 from STR using awk.

The following works:

```
info1=$(echo $STR | awk '{split($0,a,":::")} END{print a[1]}')
info2=$(echo $STR | awk '{split($0,a,":::")} END{print a[2]}')
info3=$(echo $STR | awk '{split($0,a,":::")} END{print a[3]}')
```

The following does NOT work:

```
info1=$(echo $STR | awk '{split($0,a,"$DEL")} END{print a[1]}')
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since DEL is your shell variable, you should be using something like:

```
info1=$(echo $STR | awk -v delimeter="$DEL" '{split($0,a,delimeter)} END{print a[1]}')
```